I can't see the inline errors in VS Code Python, how do i fix this?
I have managed to somehow lose the inline error popup in Python when there is an error in the codebase. I have attached an image of it here with some obviously broken code:

In my main program whenever I get an error all I see is a yellow bar on the line where the error occurs but the error is not displayed inside the editor, only in the terminal after the program crashes:
]
If it helps in providing some context, the script where the error occurs is being ran via another script in my program. I was getting the red box before but I clicked the little X to get rid of it during that execution but it hasn't come back since.

I can't reproduce the problem myself by just clicking the X, but maybe you did something else too and someone will know what happened. Although, it'd probably help to provide a [mre]. I'm thinking there could be something in your code itself that's stopping the error from appearing.

BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and see [ask] if you want more tips.

Is there any update? Can you provide a sample to help us reproduce your problem?
